# Sorting xml file alphabetically by name tag

Tags: xml, sorting, alphabetical

I have several large xml files in the following format:

```
<item>
<name>Name 1</name>
<info>Details 1</info>
</item>

<item>
<name>Name 3</name>
<info>Details 3</info>
</item>

<item>
<name>Name 2</name>
<info>Details 2</info>
</item>
```

Over time of adding to these it has become ugly. I would like to sort them alphabetically by name tag.  I have searched here and found a few different python scripts but they did not work for me.  Here is one example of what I've tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")

container = tree.find("item")

data = []
for elem in container:
    key = elem.findtext("name")
    data.append((key, elem))

data.sort()

container[:] = [item[-1] for item in data]

tree.write("test-out.xml")
print "File Written"
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to have XQuery or XSLT in your toolkit for this kind of job.

In XQuery:

```
<items>{
  for $i in //item order by $i/name return $i
}</items>
```

In XSLT (1.0 or later):

```
<items xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:for-each select="//item">
    <xsl:sort select="name"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</items>
```