# XQuery XML Alphabetizer ignoring "The" as first word in name while sorting

Tags: xml, xquery, alphabetized

This is kind of a run-on from an older question I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53473823/sorting-xml-file-alphabetically-by-name-tag) where Michael Kay supplied a great XQuery solution to sorting my xml file.  However I am now hoping to use the same code and have it ignore "The" as a first word in a name while sorting but not remove it from the file.
Here is the Code provided by Michael:

```
    <items>{
      for $i in //item order by $i/name return $i
    }</items>
```

I have been googling the death out of this for a long time.  I canno even figure out what the proper term is when "The" is used as the first word in a title or name.  It must have a name lol.  Thank you for any help yet again team.  Appreciate all the help you guys provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore “The” in your title, just add a new variable with the adjusted title, and use this in your `order by` clause:

```
<items>{
    for $i in //item 
    let $name-sort-key := 
        if (starts-with($i/name, "The ")) then
            substring-after($i/name, "The ")
        else
            $i/name
    order by $name-sort-key
    return 
        $i
}</items>
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Joe's suggestion, you could also use the `replace` function with the pattern `'^The '` as it only matches `The` at the beginning of the string:

```
for $i in //item order by replace($i/name, '^The ', '') return $i
```